# Extract a pattern from the string given below in python

Tags: python, regex

```
string_input = 'HijesProvincia:GuadalajaraUTM X:499.028CC.AA.:Comunidad Autónoma de Castilla-La ManchaUTM Y:4.567.841Huso:30Cota:1244 m.s.n.m.Tipo de punto:'
```

In this string I have to extract `UTM X:499.028`  and `UTM Y:4.567.841`.

I want a generalized way to parse this format because the numbers will be of different length. But all the string inputs will be of similar structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should detail the precise pattern that can appear and how much the string around it can change.
But assuming you search for 'UTM X:'  or 'UTM Y:' followed by a sequence of digits groups separated by a dot in a generic string you can use:

```
import re 
...
re.findall('(UTM [XY]:[\d.]+)', string_input)
```

that returns a list:

```
['UTM X:499.028', 'UTM Y:4.567.841']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. Depending on whether the text in between is fixed or variable, you can insert it as is in your pattern, or use `\.+`:

```
>>> import re

>>> p = re.compile('HijesProvincia:Guadalajara(UTM X:[0-9.]+).+(UTM Y:[0-9.]+)')
>>> m = p.search(string_input)
>>> m.groups()
('UTM X:499.028', 'UTM Y:4.567.841')
```

Note that I use `[0-9.]+` instead of `\d+` to match the number. I included the dot because the number of dots seems variable in your example.